# Combination of reduce and scan with a subject

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

RxJS version: 5.5.2

I have an array `const v = [1, 2, 3];`

I want to be able to create a Subject from this array and act like an Observable until it consumes the 1, 2, 3 values. After that I want to act like a Subject.

Here is where I'm having trouble. I need to use `reduce` on initial values `v = [1, 2, 3]` then every time the Subject adds another value to use `scan`

Here is the code:

```
const v = [1, 2, 3];
const sub = new Subject<number>();
const observable = sub.pipe(
  startWith(0),
  concatMap(x => from(v)),
  scan((a, b) => { // or reduce
    return a + b;
  }, 0),
);
observable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

If I'm using `scan` here this is printed on console

```
1
3
6
```

What I want to be printed is just last value `6`. Replacing `scan` with `reduce` will do the job only if subject is completed(that way I can't send any more values in the future).

Then every time the subject sends a value `sub.next(4);` to print `10` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `skipWhile()` to skip the first N emissions from `scan` that you don't want:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import { from } from "rxjs/observable/from";
import { of } from "rxjs/observable/of";
import { merge, concatMap, scan, skipWhile, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const v = [1, 2, 3];
let skipFirst;

const sub = new Subject<number>();

const observable = of(v).pipe(
  tap(arr => skipFirst = arr.length),
  concatMap(arr => from(arr)),
  merge(sub),
  scan((a, b) => { // or reduce
    return a + b;
  }, 0),
  skipWhile(() => --skipFirst > 0),
);
observable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

sub.next(5);
```

This prints:

```
6
11
```